# R: Faster version of "%in%"? [revised]

Tags: r

I have a large program that (alas) extensively uses the %in% operator. As our data grows in size, the program is running slowly -- and the problem appears to be the %in% operator. Below are some details of the problem.

I have a list of badwords, and I'd like to match an input list to the badwords.

```
input.words=c("hi","sample","badword")
bad.words=c("badword","badword2","badword3")

flag=which(input.words %in% bad.words)
# Do something with the flagged inputs ...
```

The input words (and bad words) are starting to become quite large, despite initially being small. The program is getting slower around %in%.

Is there a faster implementation of this operator? Or any other way to accomplish the same goal in parallel or more quickly? Many thanks in advance. Help!

Comment: I think the task is going to be  O(n^2), i.e scaling poorly, so it seems unlikely that you can get improvement unless there is some hashing strategy you can develop that allows incremental steps to build some sort of index for accumulating data.

Comment: Take a look at `%chin%` in `data.table` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385259/will-using-chin-to-subset-character-columns-of-an-auto-indexed-data-table-ever)